# setDarkTheme is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling

Whenever am clicking on Dark button which should apply darktheme on my page but instead its through this error seems like error is somewhere in button onClick not able to figure it out.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amv9b.png)

```
App.js

import { useState } from 'react';
import  Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import  Footer  from './components/Footer';
import  Routes  from './components/Routes';

const App = () =>{
    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className={darkTheme ? 'dark' : ''}>
           <div className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-200 min-h-screen">
                <Navbar darkTheme={darkTheme} setDarkTheme={setDarkTheme}/>
                <Routes/>
                <Footer/>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;


Navbar.js

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';

const Navbar = ({ darkTheme, setDarkTheme }) => {
    return (
        <div className="p-5 pb-0 flex flex-wrap sm:justify-between justify-center items-center border-b dark:border-gray-700 border-gray-200">
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center space-x-5 w-screen">
                <Link to="/">
                    <p className="text-2xl bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white py-1 px-2 rounded dark:bg-gray-white dark:text-gray-900">
                        Google
                    </p>
                </Link>

                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => setDarkTheme(!darkTheme)}
                    className="text-xl dark:bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-900 bg-white border rounded-full px-2 py-1 hover:shadow-lg"
                >{darkTheme ? 'Light' : 'Dark'}
                </button>
            </div>
            <Search />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Error message:
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
setDarkTheme is not a function
TypeError: setDarkTheme is not a function
at onClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:223:24)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14249:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14293:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14350:35)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14364:29)
at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18508:7)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18534:11)
at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18545:9)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18554:7)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18714:16

i dont have idea whats going on

Comment: Try console logging setDarkTheme in the Navbar component.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

If code-sandbox was provided it would have been of great help.

Can we just change the approach if its fine for you? Also the naming conventions will be meaningful for switching between light and dark theme.

Here is the implementation: (We are just moving the onClick callback in App component)

```
App.js

import { useState } from 'react';
import  Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import  Footer  from './components/Footer';
import  Routes  from './components/Routes';

const App = () =>{
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme(!darkTheme)
  }

    return (
        <div className={darkTheme ? 'dark' : ''}>
           <div className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-200 min-h-screen">
                <Navbar darkTheme={darkTheme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme}/>
                <Routes/>
                <Footer/>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;


Navbar.js

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';

const Navbar = ({ darkTheme, toggleTheme }) => {
    return (
        <div className="p-5 pb-0 flex flex-wrap sm:justify-between justify-center items-center border-b dark:border-gray-700 border-gray-200">
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center space-x-5 w-screen">
                <Link to="/">
                    <p className="text-2xl bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white py-1 px-2 rounded dark:bg-gray-white dark:text-gray-900">
                        Google
                    </p>
                </Link>

                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => toggleTheme()}
                    className="text-xl dark:bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-900 bg-white border rounded-full px-2 py-1 hover:shadow-lg"
                >{darkTheme ? 'Light' : 'Dark'}
                </button>
            </div>
            <Search />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```